# Best way to report crash logs alongside console logs on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, logging, crash-reports

There are some crashes that are very hard to reproduce locally and it would be nice to see the console logs at the time of the crash. Right now we intercept all NSLog and print statements and save them in a cached file (size limited).

Is there a way to catch all exceptions on iOS and before the crash happens upload that log file to S3, and then let the crash proceed? If I do this will I still be able to see the crash data on iTunes Connect and see the crash stack traces in Xcode Device Organizer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use crashlytics. But it will give same reports as you can see from device organizer.

Also you can add logs to a array and save it in NSUserdefaults. When app opened send logs to your server, so after crash when you open app you can get logs. -dont do this at release version.

Comment: When you use Crashalytics does it still allow you to use the Device Organizer for crash reports or does it completely replace all crash reporting from Apple with its own?

Comment: Yes you can still use device organizer for crash reports. "Settings>Privacy>Diagnostics&Usage" setting must be "Automatically Send" and "Share With App Developers" setting must be enabled to get crash reports from users devices. But at most of the devices this setting is closed. Becouse of this we are using Crashlytics.